# Moving mouse thru websocket in python

Tags: python, websocket, mouse

I'm sending the X and Y vector of the position I need the mouse to go to and then I use the mouse Library to move it to that position, but whenever it should move the mouse it dose not. I'm hosting both the client and server on 1 machine.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import mouse

async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            messageWS = await websocket.recv()
            message = messageWS.split(';')
            stringLen = len(message)

            if stringLen%2 == 0:
                X = message[0:stringLen//2]
                Y = message[stringLen//2:]
                Xnew = X[0]
                Ynew = Y[0]
                mouse.move(Xnew, Ynew)

            else:
                X = message[0:(stringLen//2+1)]
                Y = message[(stringLen//2+1):]
                Xnew = X[0]
                Ynew = Y[0]
                mouse.move(Xnew, Ynew)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 3000)
print("WS up!")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I'd expect the mouse to move since the server is hosted on my machine and the client is too, so if I'd send the Vector X as 10 and Y as 10 also, I'd want it to move my mouse to that position.

Comment: Can you post the client code too please. Have you checked that its sending the expected messages?

Comment: ```local websock = WebSocket.connect("ws://localhost:3000")

websock:Send(0 ..';'.. 0)``` This is in lua so you might not be know what it sends, but it would send ```0;0```

Comment: Can anyone please help?